# Is there an easy way to run Garbage Collection outside of the request cycle in Passenger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger, mod-rails

Unicorn has [OobGC](http://rubyforge.org/pipermail/mongrel-unicorn/2010-May/000510.html) rack middleware that can be used to run `GC.start` after a certain number of requests.

Is there a similar sort of thing in Phusion Passenger?

Comment: If you have a memory leak why not deal with it head on?

Comment: It isn't actually a memory leak, it's just that sometimes I have to use a lot of memory. I would rather take the hit of the GC outside of the request/response cycle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hooking into `PhusionPassenger::Rack::RequestHandler#process_request()` is the only mechanism I have found.

To do this in a similar way to the Unicorn OobGC, you can use the following module:

```
module PassengerOobGC
  def self.install!(path, interval = 5)
    self.const_set :OOBGC_PATH,     path
    self.const_set :OOBGC_INTERVAL, interval
    @@oob_nr = interval
    PhusionPassenger::Rack::RequestHandler.send :include, self
  end

  def self.included(base)
    base.send :alias_method_chain, :process_request, :gc
  end

  def process_request_with_gc(env, *args)
    process_request_without_gc(env, *args)

    if OOBGC_PATH =~ env["PATH_INFO"] && ((@@oob_nr -= 1) <= 0)
      @@oob_nr = OOBGC_INTERVAL
      GC.start
    end
  end
end
```

and invoke it in an initializer with:

```
if defined?(PhusionPassenger::Rack::RequestHandler)
  require 'passenger_oob_gc'
  PassengerOobGC.install!(%r{^/admin/}, 3)
end
```

Comment: After tuning GC environment variables (we're using REE 1.8.7) things are humming along - but when I added this code to do GC outside of req/resp cycle everything slowed down (significantly; 50%+ slower).

How did the above code affect performance for you?

Comment: Hmm, this also appears to break the New Relic agent.  Have you revised this at all?

Comment: So, this code just kills my app instance after the request completes and then passenger spawns a new app.  Not very performant.  Have you watched the PIDs of your app instances when doing this?

Comment: I just tested this by replacing the _GC.start_ with _sleep 10_, and it seems this solution is not correct (anymore) as the sleep delays the request. The answer below by Matthew seems to work on the other hand.

Answer (score 5):

Phusion Passenger 4 officially introduces an out of band garbage collection mechanism. It's more flexible than Unicorn's by allowing any arbitrary work, not just garbage collection. http://blog.phusion.nl/2013/01/22/phusion-passenger-4-technology-preview-out-of-band-work/

Answer (score 2):

You have to patch Passenger.  Doing a `GC.start` after each request has been handed off ensures that garbage collection never occurs while holding a client request.  This is a one-line change that you might consider if you're trying to reduce your average request time.

In lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb, patch `accept_and_process_next_request` and add the `GC.start` call at the end, with an appropriate interval.

See [this commit](https://github.com/wbharding/passenger/commit/58dae4baf153de30dbfae5cf0e0c38bc653b366d) for an example (thanks, @raphaelcm).

Comment: Do you have a link to the change you're referring to?

Comment: according to this post: http://www.williambharding.com/blog/uncategorized/rails-3-performance-abysmal-to-good-to-great/, you can have rails GC inbetween requests by adding this line of code to Passenger: https://github.com/wbharding/passenger/commit/58dae4baf153de30dbfae5cf0e0c38bc653b366d

Comment: Ah, sorry.  I never followed up on this post and just saw this update.  The patch @raphaelcm posted is in fact what I was alluding to.